# GNUPG non interactive over WINDOWS

Tags: windows, powershell, gnupg

I´m trying to encrypt with a symetric password a file from command line with gnupg to include it in a powershell script.
I need a non interactive gnupg cmd command line, I have been trying  with:

```
gpg --passphrase supersecret -c  c:\File\aa.jpg
```

and

```
echo supersecret| gpg -c --passphrase-fd=0 c:\File\aa.jpg
```

But both ways  appears for a windows form window.

And this way don´t appears a windows form but I can´t decrypt it:

```
gpg.exe --batch --passphrase-fd 0 -c  c:\File\aa.jpg < supersecret
```

Error decrypting:

```
gpg.exe --decrypt c:\File\aa.jpg
gpg: datos cifrados CAST5
gpg: cifrado con 1 frase contrase±a
gpg: DBG: borrada frase de paso en cachÚ con ID: S5DE110F2F3E16E83
gpg: descifrado fallido: Bad session key
```

Any idea?

Comment: Was my fault, the line gpg.exe --batch --passphrase-fd 0 -c  c:\File\aa.jpg < supersecret  
supersecret  is a file which contains the password in plain text and to decypt you need use gpg aa.jpg.gpg without --decrypt parameter

Comment: Better post it as an answer to your own question; others having a similar problem in future might recognize the solution easier then.

Answer (score 1):

Was my fault, the line gpg.exe --batch --passphrase-fd 0 -c c:\File\aa.jpg < supersecret supersecret is a file which contains the password in plain text and to decypt you need use gpg aa.jpg.gpg without --decrypt parameter